# Como hacer un flip box en el que el div oculto se deslice hacia arriba

Tags: html, css

necesito hacer un flip box en el que el div oculto se deslice hacia arriba al pasar el cursor del mouse, como el de esta página "https://www.igroupsolution.com/hsbc-empleados/", de momento tengo este ejemplo "https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_flip_box2", pero lo necesito como el de la página. Espero alguien me pueda ayudar. Gracias